# Use @Embeddable Without Nested JSON

Tags: java, embeddable, jpa

I'm trying to use the [@Embedded and @Embeddable](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-embedded-embeddable) javax annotations to keep my Java classes cleaner, but I want the resulting JSON to be flattened.

THE DESIRED BEHAVIOR:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "6edbced5-2d27-4257-a140-2925291daaf6",
        "name": "Online Maria DB",
        "address": "Syble Forks",
        "city": "Dallas",
        "state": "Texas",
        "country": "United States"
        "phoneNumber": "(789) 740-5789",
        "orgUserName": "online-maria"
    }
]
```

THE ACTUAL BEHAVIOR:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "6edbced5-2d27-4257-a140-2925291daaf6",
        "name": "Online Maria DB",
        "addressDetails": {
            "address": "Syble Forks",
            "city": "Dallas",
            "state": "Texas",
            "country": "United States"
        },
        "phoneNumber": "(789) 740-5789",
        "orgUserName": "online-maria"
    }
]
```

Is this possible using these annotation?

What I have so far:

**Organization.java**

```java
@Embedded
private Address address;
```

**Address.java**

```java
@Embeddable
public class Address {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please share what you have done so far.

Comment: Made an edit and added it to my question.

Comment: I assume you use `Jackson` for serialize these objects right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jackson's `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation if you do use `Jackson`. Also you can write custom serializer as well

```
public class Organization {

    @JsonUnwrapped
    @Embedded
    private Address address;
   
    // other code
}
```